# Can't locate installed package (type or namespace could not be found)

Tags: c#

I'm trying to install a NuGet package and the installation seems to be going fine:

```
@ D:\Dev\PGF_Test
$ dotnet add package PGFSharp --version 3.8.1-devel
  Determining projects to restore...
  Writing C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp71D3.tmp
info : Adding PackageReference for package 'PGFSharp' into project 'D:\Dev\PGF_Test\PGF_Test.csproj'.
info : Restoring packages for D:\Dev\PGF_Test\PGF_Test.csproj...
info : Package 'PGFSharp' is compatible with all the specified frameworks in project 'D:\Dev\PGF_Test\PGF_Test.csproj'.
info : PackageReference for package 'PGFSharp' version '3.8.1-devel' added to file 'D:\Dev\PGF_Test\PGF_Test.csproj'.
info : Committing restore...
info : Generating MSBuild file D:\Dev\PGF_Test\obj\PGF_Test.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
info : Writing assets file to disk. Path: D:\Dev\PGF_Test\obj\project.assets.json
log  : Restored D:\Dev\PGF_Test\PGF_Test.csproj (in 227 ms).
```

but when I write the using and `dotnet build`, I get a namespace could not be found. I've tried removing and re-adding, I've tried different names like PGF and PGFSharp.PGF, and I've tried making a fresh console application and adding it there to make sure nothing's interfering.

Anyone know what the issue might be?

I'm on .NET core on Windows 10, version 5.0.201. I checked the Github for the package I'm importing and it seems to be built in 4.5.1, could that be the issue? If so I might try recompiling the source locally.

Comment: PGFSharp is a .NET Framework project, you said you're using .NET Core. That wont work, you cannot use a .NET Framework project directly from .NET Core

Comment: I see. They should really have NuGet mention that instead of the "is compatible with all the specified frameworks in project" that makes everything look fine.
I guess I'll try forking it and changing the target to .NET Core, thanks!